# Custom post type URl Cutomization

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, custom-taxonomy, slug

I am creating a custom CPT where I have customized CPT URL structure of CPT, I am using the rewrite rule for this but it is conflicting This is a Lessons CPT, and I want to remove lessons from the URL and if any category or subcategory is selected in the post then the URL structure should be parent category/child-category/post name, I have also customized the category URL structure where I want to remove lesson-category in this example:- http://localhost/custom_theme/lesson-category/california/ the URL should be like this http://localhost/custom_theme/california/

I have Custom Lessons CPT where I want to customize the URl structure Here is the scenario:-

I want to remove the lesson in Custom CPT - http://localhost/custom_theme/lesson/paino_lesson/ the URL should be like this http://localhost/custom_theme/paino_lesson/

if any category or subcategory is selected in the post then the URL structure should be parent category/child category/post name,

I want to remove the lesson category in this example:- http://localhost/custom_theme/lesson-category/california/ the URL should be like this http://localhost/custom_theme/california/

// START: CPT 'Lessons'

```
add_action('init', 'register_lessons_post_type');
function register_lessons_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => 'Lesson',
        'singular_name'         => 'Lesson',
        'menu_name'             => 'Lesson',
        'add_new'               => 'Add New Lesson',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Add New Lesson',
        'edit_item'             => 'Edit Lesson',
        'new_item'              => 'New Lesson',
        'view_item'             => 'View Lesson',
        'view_items'            => 'View Lessons',
        'search_items'          => 'Search Lessons',
        'not_found'             => 'No lesson found',
        'not_found_in_trash'    => 'No lesson found in trash',
        'all_items'             => 'All Lessons',
        'archives'              => 'Lessons',
        'attributes'            => 'Template',
        'insert_into_item'      => 'Insert into lesson',
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => 'Uploaded to this lesson',
        'filter_items_list'     => 'Filter lessons list',
        'items_list_navigation' => 'Lesson list navigation',
        'items_list'            => 'Lessons list',
        'item_published'        => 'Lesson published',
        'item_published_privately' => 'Lesson published privately',
        'item_reverted_to_draft'    => 'Lesson reverted to draft',
        'item_scheduled'            => 'Lesson scheduled',
        'item_updated'              => 'Lesson updated',
        'taxonomies'               => array( 'lesson_category' ), // Link to the custom taxonomy
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'rewrite'            => array('slug' => '/%lesson_category%'), // Set the custom permalink structure
        'menu_position'      => 5,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-location-alt',
        'supports'           => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'elementor'),
    );

    register_post_type('lessons', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'register_lesson_category_taxonomy');
function register_lesson_category_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'City',
        'singular_name' => 'City',
        'search_items' => 'Search City',
        'all_items' => 'All Cities',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent City or State',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent City or State:',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit City',
        'update_item' => 'Update City',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New City',
        'new_item_name' => 'New City Name',
        'menu_name' => 'Cities or Locations',
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => '/', // Set the slug for the 'lesson_category' taxonomy
            'with_front' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true
        ),
    );

    // Link this taxonomy to the 'lessons' custom post type
    register_taxonomy('lesson_category', array('lessons'), $args);
}

// Change the permalink structure for the lessons post type
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_lessons_permalink_structure', 10, 4);
function custom_lessons_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample) {
    if ('lessons' === $post->post_type && 'publish' === $post->post_status) {
        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'lesson_category');

        if (!empty($terms)) {
            $term_slugs = array();

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                // Traverse through parent categories and add them to the array
                $parent_chain = get_ancestors($term->term_id, 'lesson_category');
                $parent_chain = array_reverse($parent_chain);
                foreach ($parent_chain as $parent_id) {
                    $parent_term = get_term($parent_id, 'lesson_category');
                    $term_slugs[] = $parent_term->slug;
                }

                $term_slugs[] = $term->slug;
            }

            $post_link = home_url('/') . implode('/', $term_slugs) . '/' . $post->post_name . '/';
        } else {
            // No category selected, keep the URL simple
            $post_link = home_url('/') . $post->post_name . '/';

            
        }
    }

    return $post_link;
}

// Add the %lesson_category% tag to the rewrite rules
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'custom_lessons_rewrite_rules');
function custom_lessons_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $new_rules = array();

    $terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'lesson_category', 'hide_empty' => false));

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $term_path = $term->slug;
        $new_rules[$term_path . '/([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?lesson_category=$matches[1]';
    }

    // Add a rule for the case when no category is selected
    $new_rules['([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?lessons=$matches[1]';

    return $new_rules + $rules;
}
```

Comment: What is that `custom_theme`? But you should understand that those `lesson` and `lesson-category` (which are known as rewrite slugs or base) are needed so that when the post or category page are visited, WordPress will know what should be displayed on that page, e.g. the post `Foo Post` if the URL was `http://localhost/custom_theme/lesson/foo-post/`, or the category `Foo Category` if the URL was `http://localhost/custom_theme/lesson-category/foo-category/`. So you should keep the rewrite slugs and ensure they're unique.

Comment: I'm working on a local server, and 'custom_theme' is the folder name for my WordPress installation. I've added a custom post type (CPT) called 'Lessons.' My goal is to remove the base slug for this CPT. When any category is selected, I want the  URLs to appear like this: 'http://example.com/california if any subcategory is selected I want the  URLs to appear like 'http://example.com/california/san-diego/ for a subcategory.